# Efficient way of concatenating vectors

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a n x 3 matrix `E`, a lot of means stocked in a d x 3 matrix `M` and a covariance matrix, say identity.

I want to compute, for each point in `M`, the `mvnpdf(E[i,:],M(k,:),cov)`.

Basically, when I run `mvnpdf(E,M(k,:),cov)`, I get a vector

```
[mvnpdf(E(1,:),M(k,:),cov)
mvnpdf(E(2,:),M(k,:),cov) etc]
```

I want to cat these vectors to get a matrix like:

```
[mvnpdf(E,M(1,:),cov), mvnpdf(E,M(2,:),cov), etc]
```

Is there any way to do that without a for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works on my machine, but see if it is what you are after:

```
Cov = eye(3);
C = arrayfun(@(x,y,z) mvnpdf(E,[x y z],Cov), M(1,:), M(2,:), M(3,:),'uni',false);
A = [C{:}]
```

Note: Consider not using `cov` as a variable because it is a MATLAB function.

**EDIT**: My original output `M` clobbered your input `M`.  Please try again with original data!